# Tower of Pisa function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to construct a 'smooth' function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow [0,1]$ such that all level sets $$\{ x | f(x)=y\}$$ are **circles** in a way that $f$ looks like the 'Leaning Tower of Pisa'.
Similar to this example,
[image]

but with circular level sets such that the circles get shifted and bigger towards the ground.

**Edit:** The problem is to find $s,r$ such that
$$(x-s(t))^2+y^2= r^2(t),$$
where $t\in [0,1]$ is the level. And the circle in $t+h$ is encompassed in circle $t$. If I'm not mistaken this is the case when
$$r'(t)<-|s'(t)|.$$
$f$ is then implicitly given by the equation

$$(x-s(f(x,y)))^2 + y^2 = r^2(f(x,y)).$$

What are valid choices for $s,r$ such that $f$ is nicely?

Comment: How about using an STL file?

Comment: I know STL from 3D printing. It would be good if `Derivative` could be applied to $f$.

Comment: For a general way to construct it from first principles: 1. Take a straight cone.
2. Apply a [shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping) to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $r : [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,\infty[$ be decreasing with
$r(0)=\infty$ and $r(1)=0$.

For $c\in [0,1[$ set $s:= c r$ then
$$r'(t') < -|s'(t)|$$
and $$(x-c r(f(x,y)))^2 + y^2= r^2(f(x,y))$$
such that
$$f(x,y)= r^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{c^2-1}\left(c x \pm \sqrt{x^2-(c^2-1)y^2}\right)\right).$$
$r^{-1}$ just has to be chosen such that $f$ is differentiable, e.g., $r^{-1}(t)=\exp(-t^2)$. Here, $c$ allows to adjust the tilt ($c=0$ no tilt, $c\rightarrow 1$ maximal).

[image]

You can also use other functions like $r^{-1}(t)=1-t^2$ to create other towers such as the Burj al Arab.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The equation of a circle at offset $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r$ is $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$.
Therefore we can make the tower if we make $x_0$, $y_0$, and $r$ a function of height, moving $(x_0,y_0)$ along a line and shrinking $r$ as we go:

```
With[{a = 0.6, b = 0.3},
 Show[
  ContourPlot3D[(x - a*t)^2 + (y - b*t)^2 == 
    0.04/t^2 (1 - t) + t (1 - t), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8], 
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, t}, t]}, Axes -> None]
  , Graphics3D[{Thick, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, 1}}]}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: pisa]

The `{a = 0.6, b = 0.3}` controls the direction of the tower, while the expression `0.04/t^2 (1 - t) + t (1 - t)` controls the radius.

Here's why I chose this specific expression for the radius: When `t` is near zero  the radius behaves as `0.04/t^2` so you get infinitely large circles creating an infinitely large base shrinking to form a nice smooth join with the tower. As `t` approaches 1, the radius is more like `(1 - t)` and shrinks to zero near the top creating the tower cap.

Comment: That goes into the right direction. Problem, I don't think it's a function, because a vertical line would intersect it twice not once in certain areas.

Comment: It is a function if you avoid extreme slopes and you could also increase 0.04 to 0.4.

Comment: A criterion would be that a circle has to fit inside all lower circles.

Comment: @darksun "Problem, I don't think it's a function, because a vertical line would intersect it twice not once in certain areas." -- You can use a pair of functions for the "above" and "below" parts.

Comment: @darksun use `(x - t)^2 + y^2 == 1/t^2 - 1/t + t - t^2` or if you want a cone-like function without the base: `(x - t)^2 + y^2 == (1 - t)^2` . Both of these are derived by examining this: `Graphics[Table[
  With[{r = 1 - t},
   Circle[{r, 0}, r]]
  , {t, 0.01, 1, 0.01}]]`

Comment: @flinty Yap that does work. I need it with base. But I don't think $f$ can be given explicitly here.

Comment: @darksun there _is_ an explicit form though it's not that useful. You just take this equation and `Solve` for `t`. The trouble is the form is very complex and contains lots of radicals.

Comment: Right, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 5):

*(Extended comment, not an answer.)*

Imported the STL file from here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2733780/files .

One approach would be to use intersections of this STL-file mesh object with planes orthogonal to the X-axis and derive (pairs of) functions over a certain set of X values.

```
rgSTLPisa = 
  Quiet[Import[
    "https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/10/ba/d8/e6/06/Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa.stl"]];
Show[rgSTLPisa, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
Show[rgSTLPisa, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 20}, All, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: Surely, its not a smooth function, but a nice find. Might be also interesting for modelers.

Comment: To whoever downvoted -- I think this answer-comment helped OP to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 4):

**Reply the comment**

According my original answer,we can rewrite my equation to get the two functions `s[t]` and `r[t]`.

```
s[t_]=t/2;
r[t_]=Sqrt[-Log[t]]
```

seems work toward your new edition.

```
Plot[Sqrt[-Log[t]], {t, 0, 1}]
Limit[Sqrt[-Log[t]], t -> 0]
```

[image]

**Original**

My approach just as flinty by use `ContourPlot3D`, and my idea is use the deformation of the Gauss function `Exp[-t^2]`

```
ContourPlot3D[
 z == Exp[-((x - z/2)^2 + y^2)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 20, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea! What would be $s$ and $r$ here from 'Edit' in the question?

Comment: @darksun  `Sqrt[-Log[t]]` work!  see my updated.

Comment: Yes, $r'$ is smaller than $-1$ so smaller than $s'$. What would be the maximal slope if you introduce a parameter?

Comment: @darksun  `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  z == Exp[-((x - c*z)^2 + y^2)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All, MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"], {c, 0, 2}]`  maybe 0<=c<=1

Comment: $c=\sqrt{e/2}$ seems to be the maximal value.

Comment: The only big problem here is that $f$ can't be given explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[pisaF]
pisaF[ρ_: 1/2, μ0_: {0, 0}, μ1_: {3, 3}, σ_: {1, 1}] := 
  PDF[BinormalDistribution[(1 - #3) μ0 + #3 μ1, σ, ρ]][{#, #2}] &;

Row[RegionPlot3D[z <= #[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#2, 16], ImageSize -> Medium, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], PlotPoints -> 60, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None] & @@@ 
  {{pisaF[1/2], "pisaF[1/2]"}, {pisaF[0],  "pisaF[0]"}, 
   {pisaF[-2/3, {0, 0}, -{3, 3}], "pisaF[-2/3, {0, 0}, -{3, 3}]"}}]
```

[image]

```
Row[RegionPlot3D[z <= #[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, 0, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 10, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotLabel -> Style[#2, 16], ImageSize -> Medium, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 90, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, 
    Boxed -> False] & @@@ 
 {{pisaF[], "pisaF[]"}, {pisaF[0], "pisaF[0]"},
  {pisaF[-2/3, {0, 0}, -{3, 3}],  "pisaF[-2/3, {0, 0}, -{3, 3}]"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: stacked offset cylinders]

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[{Hue[(3 - z)/3], 
   Cylinder[{{2, z, z}, {2, z, z + .1}}, (3 - z)*2]}, {z, 0, 3, .1}] ]
```

This doesn't help you, but I thought I'd play with stacked cylinders, following a simple offset path and with the radius being twice the quantity of 3-z. Since I tend to abuse my parameters, I just colored each cylinder based on that same parameter.